# How to collate all necessary Pyinstaller hidden import without having to troubleshoot whenever running the exe hits an error

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, exe

I have successfully converted .py to .exe but encounter errors when running the executable, largely due to hidden-imports issues. Examples of errors: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils._cython_blas'. I have to debug one by one by re-running Pyinstaller which is time-intensive.

Can someone guide the way to collate a list of necessary hidden-imports effectively for converting .py to .exe using Pyinstaller.

What should I do in my pyinstaller command to prevent such issues from occurring downstream.

Thanks you very much.

Comment: You could try reading the `pyinstaller` log. It's  very long but it does have the comprehensive coverage you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Thanks much @BoarGules! I refer to the error messages from shell and compiled the hidden imports in spec file. `ModuleNotFoundError` is no longer an issue. However, some hidden imports issue still recur when running with the updated spec file e.g. `scipy.spatial.transform._rotation_groups`. Other warnings gathered from shell include `Unable to find package for requirement zope.event from package gevent.` Still continue to face issues with running the exe, hoping not due to those warnings... Still in the midst of troubleshooting... Should I also refer to the warning txt from build folder?

Comment: I know too little about `scipy` or `zope` to be able to suggest anything helpfully specific. Best of luck.